# Find all the same values on a row and keep the highest absolute of another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a Data frame with this *shape*:

```
       x    y
1     1510 -125
2     1636 -125
3     1637 -125
4     1509 -124
5     1510 -124
...    ...  ...
4210  1555   68
4211  1556   68
4212  1682   68
4213  1554   69
4214  1555   69
```

I would like to find all the same values on **x** and keep just the one that has the highest absolute value on **y**.

For example on the given dataframe :

```
       x    y
1     1510 -125
...    ...  ...
5     1510 -124
...    ...  ...
4210  1555   68
...    ...  ...
4214  1555   69
```

I would like to keep

```
       x    y
1     1510 -125
...    ...  ...
4214  1555   69
```

and delete the other values with **same x** and **lower y**.

Comment: Do you think `highest absolute of another row` ?

Comment: Yeap. 

If i have many same x, i would like to keep the x which has the highest abs y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for only one absolute maximum:

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with absolute values of `y` for indices by maximum, then select by `loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['y'].abs().groupby(df['x']).idxmax()]
print (df1)
         x    y
1     1510 -125
4214  1555   69
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.assign(y=df['y'].abs()).groupby('x')['y'].idxmax()]
```

Solution for all maximum values with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get Series filled by maximum of absolute values:

```
print (df)
         x    y
1     1510 -125
1     1510 -125
5     1510 -124
4210  1555   68
4214  1555   69

y = df['y'].abs()
df1 = df[y.groupby(df['x']).transform('max') == y]
print (df1)
         x    y
1     1510 -125
1     1510 -125
4214  1555   69
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quite explanatory answer!

Answer (score 1):

To get exact what you want you can do next way:

```
df['y_abs'] = df['y'].abs() # calculate abs
ind = df[['x','y_abs']].groupby('x').idxmax().to_numpy().flatten() #get indexes of max y_abs
df.drop(columns='y_abs').iloc[ind,:] # get rows with that indexes
```

output:

```
    x       y
0   1510    -125
3   1555    69
```

---

Solution about finding just max of `y`

It is easy to do using groupby function for DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1510, 1510, 1555, 1555], 'y':[-125,-124,68,69]})
df.groupby('x').max()
```

output:

```
          y
x   
1510    -124
1555    69
```

Comment: @jezrael you are right! Then, my solution already not so elegant :) fixed.

Comment: Thank you fopr yout time and for your quite explanatory answer!